# How to remove app name and port from url in grails?

Tags: url, grails, url-mapping

Instead of deploying my app to

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp
```

I want to deploy it to

```
http://localhost
```

Answer (score 30):

To change the run-app port, edit `grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy` and add the line

```
grails.server.port.http = 80
```

To remove the context (the 'myApp' part) edit application.properties and add the line

```
app.context=/
```

Comment: or to remove the 'myApp' part, add the following code block to `Config.groovy`: `grails.app.context="/"`. Not sure but application.properties is auto generated file, so it is safe to add in `Config.groovy`

Answer (score 5):

deploy your app to a tomcat server with the war name as ROOT.war. 
Because war names describe contexts... papa.war will be available through [root_domain]/papa

Comment: i got one more solution by googling i.e if i write grails.app.context="/" in conf.groovy file ill get url with out app name.but i when i run with -Dserver.port=80 run-app it won work as before and app name will display.

Comment: i am still in development mode not deployed yet..and i am using 80 apache port bcz i don want to display any port number in URL

Comment: SO in development how can i achieve it with default port?

Comment: but what if I have more than one Application running. I could not run them all using ROOT.war!?

Answer (score 4):

To remove the port, use:

```
grails -Dserver.port=80 run-app
```