# How do I remove the application name when running a grails app in development mode?

Tags: grails

I'm testing my application as "grails run-app".

I have read [How to remove app name and port from url in grails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989910/how-to-remove-app-name-and-port-from-url-in-grails).

I have added

grails.app.context="/"

to my Config.groovy file and my application.properties file.

I have also tried removing the "app.name" line from application.properties file. Grails doesn't honor any of those configuration parameters and puts the application name in there anyway.

Is there any reliable way of getting rid of that?

Comment: Where do have the application name? Do you reach your app at `http://localhost:8080`? If you have the app name just in your links, adjust the `grails.serverURL` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct setting is to add:

```
app.context=/
```

To `application.properties`.

I believe this changed from a `Config.groovy` setting sometime around Grails 1.2 or so.