# How to resolve Tomcat 6 400 Bad Request Error

Tags: tomcat, grails, war

Recently I have posted regarding "How can I remove the application name from a Grails application’s URL?". The solution for this was

first shutdown your tomcat [from the bin directory (`sh shutdown.sh`)] then you must delete all the content of your tomcat webapps folder (`rm -fr` *) then rename your `WAR` file to `ROOT.war` finally start your tomcat [from the bin directory (`sh startup.sh`)].

The problem with the above solution is that tomcat 6 gives me 400 bad request error whenever i access using the domain name (`http://myapp.mydomain.com`). How to resolve the issue. With IP (`http://1.x.x.x`) its working fine But the domain name it gives me error like this.

You can refer My old post [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989910/how-to-remove-app-name-and-port-from-url-in-grails)

Answer (score 0):

You should configure Tomcat `Host`: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html

If you have just one application, you can just edit existing value of `name` attribute.

But if you need to create a new application, and keep existing applications under existing hosts, then you should also setup `appBase` attribute, pinting to a different directory (it's a directory for your `ROOT.war`)

Comment: I have just added "grails.app.context = '/'" in config.grrovy and deployed war as ROOT.war in webapps. The app can be accessible at http://localhsot:8080. It is not giving any 400 bad request error. My question: Apart from these setting is it mandatory to create ROOT.xml and do the configurations.

Comment: No, it's not mandatory. You could use `ROOT.war` *OR* a `.xml` with context config